# How can I refactor code : Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie for the computer language. I try to learn about back-end web project from Youtube, but the video is launch 2 yrs ago. And now Mongoose dropped out callback support for Model.prototype.save.

I try to add new data to database it's show Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback.

How can I refactor code for run in properly.

connect to MongoDB

```
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/productDB'
mongoose.connect(dbUrl,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Add new data module

```
module.exports.saveProduct = function(model,data){
    model.save(data)
}
```

```
router.post('/insert',(req,res)=>{
    let data = new Product({
        name:req.body.name,
        price:req.body.price,
        image:req.body.image,
        description:req.body.description
    })
    Product.saveProduct(data,(err)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err)
        res.redirect('/')
    })
})
```

Error show:

throw new MongooseError('Model.prototype.save() no longer accepts a callback');
^

Answer (score 0):

Many MongoDB functions no longer accept a callback, because MongoDB utilizes promises. They've more or less been replaced by the .then() and .catch() methods.

**https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).