# MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback (error message)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

i'm trying to get result's throw model.find() but it show me this error message

> MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback

```
1. const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', moviesSchema);
2. app.get('/', (req, res) =\> {
3. Movie.find({}, function(err, movies) {
4. res.render('index', {
5. moviesList: movies })
6. })})
7. app.listen(4000, function() {
8. console.log('server is running');
9. })
```

Comment: Mongoose is based on the MongoDB Node.JS driver, which no longer accepts callbacks.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76368131/2282634

Comment: What have you done or researched to try and solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it as a promise

```js
Movie.find({}).then(movies => { 
res.render('index', {
5. moviesList: movies })
 })
```